# RAID 4 Simulation (for learning purposes)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I have created a Python 3 program that simulates a RAID 4 configuration, using lists as the simulated HDDs.**

- `a = RAID4()` creates a variable of the class `RAID4`.
- `a.convert_to("string to make raided", 4)`: `convert_to` takes a string input and a number of HDDs to create. It then turns the string into bytes, and evenly splits the bits across the HDDs, leaving the parity HDD empty. It then generates parity and stores the HDDs. A `RAID4` class object is returned.

Once this has been done you can:

- Simulate a HDD being corrupt or destroyed by `a.remove_hdd(2)`.
- Repair the RAID configuration by running `a.repair()`.
- Print a table of the HDDs by `print(a)`.
- Get the string from the HDDs by running `str = a.convert_from()`.

**What I'm asking:**

- Is there anything that can be simplified, do I have extra code that doesn't do anything?
- Are there any bugs that I haven't picked up on during my testing (I don't expect there to be any, but you never know)?
- Are there any Python conventions that I've accidentally ignored?

Bonus question (for someone with an understanding of RAID):

- Have I simulated RAID 4 correctly (is this *actually* kind of like what RAID 4 does)? I'm using bits instead of blocks.

Any other comments are appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import types


class RAID4(object):
    def __init__(self, input_str=None, hdd_num=3):
        if input_str:
            self.convert_to(input_str, hdd_num)

    class HDDNotExist(Exception):
        pass

    class NotEnoughHDDs(Exception):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the HDDs in a visual format."""
        # top border
        print_str = "====" * len(self.hdds) + "=\n"
        # columns headings
        for i in range(len(self.hdds) - 1):
            print_str += "|{:^3}".format(i)
        print_str += "|XOR|\n"
        print_str += "|" + "---+" * (len(self.hdds) - 1) + "---|\n"

        # for every row
        for i in range(len(max(self.hdds, key=len))):
            # print each column
            for j in range(len(self.hdds)):
                print_str += "| " + str(self.hdds[j][i]) + " "
            print_str += ("|\n")

        # bottom border
        print_str += "====" * len(self.hdds) + "="

        return print_str

    def xor(self, *to_xor):
        """Performs XOR on parameters, from left to right."""
        # if passed a list as it's only argument, xor everything in it
        if len(to_xor) == 1 and \
                isinstance(to_xor[0], (list, tuple, types.GeneratorType)):
            to_xor = to_xor[0]

        x = 0
        for i in to_xor:
            x ^= i
        return x

    def convert_to(self, input_str, hdd_num=3):
        """Converts a string into a set number of HDDs."""
        if hdd_num < 3:
            raise NotEnoughHDDs(
                "RAID 5 requires a minimum of three hard drives to operate.")

        # convert every character into a byte (8x bits)
        input_bin = ''.join(format(ord(x), 'b').zfill(8) for x in input_str)
        # add a 1, this, and every 0 after it will be removed when
        #   converting back into the string
        input_bin += "1"

        # number of bits required for each HDD to have a full byte
        bits_per_hdd_byte = 8 * (hdd_num - 1)

        # next lowest multiple of bits for each
        #   HDD to have a whole number of bytes
        next_lowest_multiple = len(input_bin) // bits_per_hdd_byte + 1

        # make each HDD have a whole number of bytes when input is evenly split
        input_bin += "0" * (
            next_lowest_multiple * bits_per_hdd_byte - len(input_bin))

        # make blank hdds
        self.hdds = [[] for _ in range(hdd_num)]

        # split data into hdds, with one hdd left for parity
        for i, x in enumerate(input_bin):
            self.hdds[i % (hdd_num - 1)].append(int(x))

        # xor every row
        for i in range(max(len(x) for x in self.hdds)):
            # append the row's xor
            self.hdds[-1].append(self.xor(
                self.hdds[j][i] for j in range(hdd_num - 1)
                ))

    def convert_from(self):
        """Converts HDDs into the string."""
        self.repair()

        # combine HDDs into a single list
        # zip(hdds). for i in zip. for j in i. str(j)
        output_bin = (str(j) for i in zip(*self.hdds[:-1]) for j in i)
        output_bin = ''.join(output_bin)

        # remove the last 1, and following 0s (padding)
        output_bin = output_bin.rsplit("1", 1)[0]

        # split into bytes (8x bits), one for each character
        output_bytes = [output_bin[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(output_bin), 8)]

        # decode bytes into characters, join and return
        return ''.join(chr(int(x, 2)) for x in output_bytes)

    def remove_hdd(self, index_to_remove):
        """Remove a HDD, simulating a destroyed HDD in a RAID system."""
        try:
            # sets HDD to empty list so we know theres supposed to be a HDD here
            # (instead of deleting the HDD)
            self.hdds[index_to_remove] = []
        except IndexError:
            raise HDDNotExist(
                "The HDD to remove does not exists. HDDs are 0-indexed.")

    def repair(self):
        """Creates a new HDD to replace the missing one."""
        # if a HDD is missing, repair it
        if [] in self.hdds:
            # get index (so we XOR in the right order)
            empty_hdd_index = self.hdds.index([])

            # delete the empty HDD and create the replacement
            del self.hdds[empty_hdd_index]
            new_hdd = []

            # for every data row in the HDD
            for i in range(len(self.hdds[0])):
                # get the row (one bit from each HDD)
                row = [self.hdds[j][i] for j in range(len(self.hdds) - 1)]
                # insert a 0 into the missing HDD's spot
                row.insert(empty_hdd_index, 0)

                # add a 1 or 0 to the replacement HDD depending on whether
                #   having a 0 created a matching XOR result
                new_hdd.append(0 if self.xor(row) == self.hdds[-1][i] else 1)

            # insert the replacement HDD where it belongs
            self.hdds.insert(empty_hdd_index, new_hdd)

        # if there are no HDDs missing, check that there are no corruptions
        else:
            # for every data row in the HDD 
            for i in range(len(self.hdds[0])):
                # get the row (one bit from each HDD)
                row = [self.hdds[j][i] for j in range(len(self.hdds) - 1)]

                # if the row XORed is different to what it should be
                if self.xor(row) != self.hdds[-1][i]:
                    # send a warning, saying where the error will be
                    print(
                        "WARNING: data point {} corrupted, XOR didn't match. "
                        "This will be character {} if it's a string."
                        .format(i, ((i + 1) * (len(self.hdds) - 1) // 8) + 1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hey Bob!")
    a = RAID4("hey Bob!", 4)
    print(a)
    # uncomment one of the lines below to "screw with" the HDDs
    #a.remove_hdd(2)    # this line deletes a HDD
    #a.hdds[2][5] = 0   # this line manually changes a bit
    #a.hdds[2][5] = 0 if a.hdds[2][5] else 1  # this line manually toggles a bit
    print(a)
    a.repair()
    print(a)
    print(a.convert_from())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, input_str=None, hdd_num=3):
    if input_str:
        self.convert_to(input_str, hdd_num)
```

This is a little on the obscure side. It seems the effect is to assign a value to self.hdds. But surprisingly, that does not happen always. Plus it would be nice to see a textual hint like `self.hdds = []` or `None`, which convert_to() overwrites. When reading a constructor, we're trying to learn the set of object attributes, and the sort of "good values" the code allows them to contain.

Also, please define the nested exception classes before introducing the constructor.

```
    for i in range(len(self.hdds) - 1):
        print_str += "|{:^3}".format(i)
```

This runs the risk of being quadratic, except on some versions of the cPython interpreter that extend the string in place. The usual python idiom is to `.append()` to a list in a loop, then return a string with `''.join()`. Your range is limited so it's no big deal, just a coding habit to be wary of.

Your string concatenation expressions are perfectly fine, but consider using `.format()` instead.

```
    if len(to_xor) == 1 and \
            isinstance(to_xor[0], (list, tuple, types.GeneratorType)):
```

This is fine. Consider writing it this way, without backslash:

```
    if (len(to_xor) == 1
        and isinstance(to_xor[0], (list, tuple, types.GeneratorType))):
```

A conjunction with a bunch of `and`'s lined up near the left margin is easier to read than one with ragged-right `and`'s near the right margin.

```
        self.hdds[-1].append(self.xor(
            self.hdds[j][i] for j in range(hdd_num - 1)
            ))
```

The pair of dangling close parens doesn't appear to improve clarity in this case. Sometimes a paren on its own line can be very useful, as when defining a long list constant. Here, consider making `for j` start a new line to improve clarity.

```
            "The HDD to remove does not exists. HDDs are 0-indexed.")
```

Typo: exist

```
print(a.convert_from())
```

Sorry, I didn't find that to be a very clear public API. The "from" suggests that we will be passing in an arg. Consider renaming the method.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x you do not need to specify the encoding type because  [the default one](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) is UTF-8. So you can safely remove the directive: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`